# Avoiding warning "variable is declared but never used" in try/catch block

Tags: c#, vb.net, try-catch, stack-trace, compiler-warnings

Given the following code in C#:

```
public void CatchExceptionThenThrow()
{
    try
    {
        StartThings();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I have converted that to VB as such using the dotnetfiddle VB.net converter:

```
Public Sub CatchExceptionThenThrow()
    Try
        StartThings()
    Catch As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub
```

This throws a compile error on:

```
Catch As Exception
```

> End of Statement expected

I then change that to:

```
Public Sub CatchExceptionThenThrow()
    Try
        StartThings()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub
```

But this creates a warning "variable declared but never used".  How do I go about `throw`ing rather than `throw ex`ing in VB without getting the warning, all the while preserving the entirety of the stack trace as in the first C# example?

---

All good comments, and thanks for the redundancy information I realize the try/catch is completely not needed as this would have occurred with or without the try/catch. The question was more for curiosities sake in a scenario that, I suppose, has no real basis in (a good code) reality.

I had seen something similar in a blog post about exception handling recently and why to `throw` vs `throw ex`, and was just curious as to how to accomplish the same code in VB - as I'm not strong with VB and am trying to better understand it, and exception handling.

I had hoped I'd be able to find the blog post I referenced above, but was unable.  The gist of it (which spawned the question) can be found: https://dotnetfiddle.net/741wAi

Comment: Why are you blowing up all the useful information by generically throwing in the first place? Even better, question *why are you even catching* if you are just hiding the exception information? This whole thing reeks.

Comment: `try{ StartThings(); } catch (Exception) { throw; }` is semantically the same as `StartThings(); `

Comment: @BradleyDotNET wat...OP is rethrowing the exception

Comment: @moarboilerplate Its still useless code

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I suspect moarboilerplate was pointing out that there's no information lost by this, which is what your first comment appear to imply.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Presumably he's planning on doing something before rethrowing the exception, but what he does there is irrelevant to the question, and so hasn't bothered to post it.

Comment: It probably depends on whether OP is using a derived exception and if he's just simplifying the code. If so he may need to provide a more robust example that won't attract criticism.

Comment: @WillDean Yes, I was incorrect in that statement.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan No, it's not. If you have both `finally` clauses and exception filtes, the order in which they're called will be different. And because of that, a literal `catch { throw; }` can actually make perfect sense. (It's a rare case that deserves a clarifying comment, though.)

Comment: @hvd, do you see `finally` clause in the code provided above?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Do you see the body of `StartThings`? If there are any `finally` clauses inside it, that's enough to make a difference.

Comment: @hvd, exception filters in the preview shouldn't take in account. What about calling `finally` blocks, technically, the order can't be different. They will be called by direction of stack scroll. The only difference is when the empty catch matches then the finally block will be called up to this catch, and after rethrow stack will be continued scrolling to match new catch block and the stack frames would be less on that matching.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan VB.NET has had exception filters for a long time. They're not a preview-only feature just because C# lacked support for them. Anyway, if when an exception is thrown, looking from innermost to outermost, you first have a finally block, then a catch block that simply rethrows, and finally an exception filter, then the finally block runs first, then the catch block, and the exception filter only after that. If you remove the catch block, then the exception filter runs *before* the finally block.

Comment: Great. Apologize, but I don't use VB.NET.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just have an empty `Catch` like:

```
Try
     StartThings()
Catch
    Throw
End Try
```

But if you are not doing anything in the `Catch` block other than re-throwing it, then there is no point to have `try-catch` in first place.

You can have `StartThings()` without try-catch and in case of exception, the exception will propagate to the caller.

The reason you are getting warning for `Catch ex As Exception`, is that you caught the exception in variable `ex` but you are not using it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just catching `Exception` then your code is redundant, as has been pointed out. If however you're simplifying your example code and you are trying to catch only a specific type of exception and do other processing for other thrown `Exception`s, then I hate to break it to you but it appears VB can't really do this so you'll have to put up with the warning. Obviously don't throw ex.

Comment: One can always use the variable in a way that doesn't do anything, just to shut the compiler up, i.e. `GC.KeepAlive(ex);` or something similar.

Comment: @Servy Heh, yeah, that's always an option too.